# How can I create a crosstab which loops through if case was open at the end of each quarter?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, crosstab

I am trying to create a crosstab from a Pandas Dataframe which summarizes whether or not a case was open at the end of each quarter

I dont have a problem creating a simple crosstab where say I needed to group it by exact open date, because those are already in the dataset, but I am struggling to come up with an efficient way to say to count it if the case is between the open date and the close date at the end of the quarter, which means one case can be counted more than once because it can be open for several quarters.

```
d = {'CaseID': [ID1, ID2,ID3,ID4], 'Open Date': [Jan-1, Mar-8, Apr-10,Aug-6], 'Close Date':[Apr-9,Apr-9,Dec-12,Dec-12]}
```

The output would look something like this:

Cases open on the last day of each quarter

- Q1 - 2
- Q2 - 1
- Q3 - 2
- Q4 - 0

Comment: There is no such object as *Python Dataframe*. Please tag and include all `import` lines to confirm the specific library that maintains the dataframe object: `pandas`, `pyspark`, etc.

Comment: is the date all within a year?

Comment: Not necessarily